# Amazon SP-API Getting order items in order list API

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

The Amazon SP-API **getorders API endpoint doesn't send the items of that orders**. I want to show the orders with their items like in Amazon Seller central in my inventory. Calling the get items **(getorderitems endpoint)** for every order will be unwise. Is there any other way to achieve this?

The seller central sends the order items data altogether in a single response.
[image: Amazon SP-API response like seller-central]

Answer (score 3):

SP-API was specifically set up to not include all that data in one API call. They provide the following operations for you to be able to get the specific data you need:

- getOrders
- getOrder
- getOrderBuyerInfo
- getOrderAddress
- getOrderItems
- getOrderItemsBuyerInfo
- updateShipmentStatus

**[orders-api](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/orders-api/ordersV0.md)**

So for each order you need to call the getOrderItems operation to retrieve the data you are looking for.

Comment: yes looks like it. I have to call getorderItems API every time. May run into limit issues down the road.

Comment: Yes you will. Checkout their rate-limit and burst limit in the docs. .0055 requests per second or it will just hang.

Comment: I had to add a wait in between loops to ensure I didn't exceed the rate limits.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten unhelpful - not a parallel system or choice - totally different platforms, and btw, the reason people choose amazon over shopify is the sales volume is four orders of magnitude higher.

Comment: @kevinc I disagree. You can integrate Amazon Sales data into Shopify and then export gigabytes of detailed order data easily, without having to tackle a badly implemented API.

Comment: Rate limiting is complicated as the limit they provide is the number of requests they add to your "bucket" every second, not the number of requests you can execute per second.  The use of next tokens complicates this.  Basically I look for an http error 429, and then incrementally increase a delay on every subsequent loop until no more 429.  Through trial and error I've found that getting smaller batches every 30 to 60 minutes instead of big batches a few times a day generally avoids throttling, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can download Orderreports (possible via the api  as well as Website) there is one which contains all the data you want (you may have to set up a regular generation of this report)

hth hannes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).